# Os x Mavericks ruby app

Tags: ruby, macos, macruby

Does anyone know how to package and develop a ruby application? Python has pyobjc, Ruby used to have macruby but that does not seem to support OS X Mavericks.  Hence I'm looking for alternatives.  I'd like to build an app using ruby (and cocoa) but can't seem to find any documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Check out RubyMotion.
It's a commercial toolchain for developing OSX and iOS apps. 
http://www.rubymotion.com/

Comment: I'm a student, $200 seems a bit steep.  Any cheaper alternatives?

Comment: I'm not sure if RubyCocoa has any way of bundling apps, but you might check into that. It's free.